# $dateToString on array items

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I have the following Mongo document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e6cb45a902f0f3ea1e35cc"),
    "title" : "Book 1",
    "authors" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Adam",
            "birthday" : ISODate("1982-03-22T22:41:19.198Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I project the authors' birthday with `$dateToString`.  Right now I have

```
db.getCollection('coll')
  .aggregate([
     {$match: {}}, 
     {$project: 
        {  
          title: 1, 
          authors: {
            name: 1, 
            birthday: { 
              $dateToString: { format: "%m", date: "$birthday" } 
            } 
          }
        } 
      }
])
```

but `$birthday` isn't finding the current author's birthday, and is returning `null` instead.  And I've tried every other possibility I can think of.  All either error out or return null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) for this sort of thing. It's usage is for reshaping arrays and some of the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) notation is a relatively new thing with only limited applications:

```
db.getCollection('coll').aggregate([
   { "$match": {}}, 
   { "$project": {  
     "title": 1, 
     "authors": {
       "$map": {
         "input": "$authors",
         "as": "item",
         "in": {
           "name": "$$item.name",
           "birthday": { 
             "$dateToString": { "format": "%m", "date": "$$item.birthday" }
           } 
         }
       }
     } 
   }}
 ])
```

That makes sure the operator is applied to the specific element of the array which is being processed, and returns the new array.

Comment: That .... could work.  Are you saying this is impossible with $project?

Comment: @AdamRackis Yes, at present at least. Whilst you can do things like `$project: { authors: { name: 1 } }` as a "shortcut" for `$map`, to actually apply something to "each array member" as a function is beyond the scope of that notation. So use the "real thing" instead.

Comment: can you please check my edit?  Your original wasn't working - what's there now seems to, though

Comment: @AdamRackis It would depend on the MongoDB version. `as` was made "optional" in MongoDB 3.2 I believe and if you don't specify it defaults to `$$this` for the current array element. I actually thought the notation of `$project` you were attempting was only available from the same version, but I could be wrong about that. I more or less just made some quick edits to the code you posted at the time I grabbed it, so I have not fully checked syntax at this time.

Comment: Ah gotcha - yeah I'm running a local version of Mongo here - thanks a ton!

Comment: Have a follow-on question here if you're so inclined :) 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815181/mongodb-sort-nested-array-in-projection